# Angular $http POST appends parameters to URL

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular so I'm probably making a basic mistake. I'm having trouble with the $http service. I'm declaring my method as a POST but the parameters are appended to the URL as if I'm using a GET. My code is below, any ideas?

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: URL,
    params: {
        Source: 'Blog',
        Header: entry.Header,
        Body: entry.Body,
        ID: entry.ID,
        IsLive: entry.IsLive
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {         
});
```

Comment: use "data" instead of "params"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably You are not defined 'entry'. Add it in the model ($scope.entry object) and look at example:

```
myControllers.factory('sqlFactory', ['$http', function($scope, $http){
var f = {};

f.get = function($scope, $http){
    var file = 'php/datasets.php';
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url: file,
        params: {
            Source: 'Blog',
            Header: $scope.entry.Header,
            Body: $scope.entry.Body,
            ID: $scope.entry.ID,
            IsLive: $scope.entry.IsLive
        }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //return record
            $scope._rows = data;
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //return error message
        $scope._error = data;
    });
};

return f;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the $http.post method in another way like this.

```
$http.post(URL{Source:'Blog',Header:entry.Header,Body:entry.Body,ID:entry.ID,IsLiv:entry.IsLive})
.success(function (data, status, headers) {
    console.log(data)
}).error(function (data, status, headers) {         
});
```

if you don't have to set something particular in the post method, you can write it in that way.
I  even suggest you to log the data Response parameters.
I don't know how many experience you have with the http methods around the web, so in the end i suggest you to open the web-developer console of your browser(i prefer to use the mozilla one) and see in the network panel the parameters you send with this method. I hope this could be a full explanation

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the "params" object? This is what is adding to your url. I am assuming that you are POSTing the params object to your server. Maybe this is what you should be doing?

```
var params = {
    Source: 'Blog',
    Header: entry.Header,
    Body: entry.Body,
    ID: entry.ID,
    IsLive: entry.IsLive
}
http.post(URL, params)
.success(function(data, status, headers,config){})
.error(function(data, status, headers,config){})
```